# Ansible: What is the alternative for the deprecated short form of vars_prompt block?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

The goal is to define variables prompting the user in an Ansible playbook.

I'm using Ansible 2.4.0.0.

[Example](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_prompts.html) in the documentation works, but reports feature deprecation:

> [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Using the 'short form' for vars_prompt has been
>   deprecated. This feature will be removed in version 2.7.

**What is the future-proof alternative for the short form of vars_prompt?**

I can seem to find it neither in the Ansible documentation nor by searching the Net.

Comment: A brief look a the doc which you linked does not yield any short form used there. All examples seem to work perfectly well without warnings. Please post a real code inside the question.

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated (short) form:

```
vars_prompt:
  variable1: "Please input variable1 value"
```

Current form:

```
vars_prompt:
  - name: "variable1"
    prompt: "Please input variable1 value"
```

---

<sup>None of the examples on the [doc page you linked](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_prompts.html) uses deprecated form.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, based on your observation I found the problem in my playbook:
```
  - prompt: "IP address:"
    default: ""
```
This form also considered as short, thus deprecated.

Comment: It’s not short, it’s just broken. Ansible does not check for every possible mistake, so when `name` is missing it assumes the old form was used.